# What function when given the inputs $x,y$ returns the given $z$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What function when given the inputs $x, y$ returns the given $z$?

- When $x = 2, y = 10$, $z = 1$
- When $x = 6, y = 10$, $z = 2$
- When $x = 50, y = 70$, $z = 5$
- When $x = 16, y = 17$, $z = 1$
- When $x = 1, y = 3$, $z = 0$
- When $x = 20, y = 30$, $z = 3$
- When $x = 100, y = 140$, $z = 9$

I'm trying to find if there is a relation between these examples.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on what it might be?

Comment: @JohnMartin I was thinking along the lines of gcd, relatively prime, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to find one function true for all? Or a different function for each?

Comment: @Smath A function true for all, but if you have one for different cases, I would like to see that too.

Comment: Ahh, well, it's actually really easy for single cases. Suppose we want to solve the problem for some specified $x$, $y$ and $z$... find a function $g$ such that $g(x,y)=0$... then an answer to the question is $f=g+z$. For example, if $x=2$, $y=10$ and $z=1$, then $f(x,y)=(x-2)h(x,y)+1$  certainly works for any $h(x,y)$.

Comment: @Smath I don't quite understnad

Comment: With regards to the specific example, if you were to plug $(x,y)=(2,10)$ into $f$, you would get back $z=1$.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to think of the values we're given as $a, b$ and $c$ and reserve $x, y$ for the variables of the polynomial.

Comment: Can you give more context? Is it a puzzle, is it a question in an exam on number theory, or polynomials, or about statistical regression?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not well defined. There need to be more constraints. I can choose for example $f(x,y)=a_0x^6+a_1x^5+a_2x^4+a_3x^3+a_4x^2+a_5x+a_6$. Note that I did not have to use $y$ at all. If I plug in your 7 conditions, I get the $a_i$ coefficients. You can replace some of the terms with some expressions depending on $y$ to some powers, or a mixture of $x$ and $y$. You cannot have an expression that is independent of x, since the first two conditions have the same $y$ and different $z$. Or I can define a trivial function $f(x,y)=0$ except the following 7 cases: f(2,10)=1, f(6,10)=2,...

Answer (score 0):

All seven of the $x$ values are different. We can disregard the $y$ values. But 
    For $1\le n\le7$ let $x_n,\,y_n,\,z_n$ denote the given values and define
    \begin{equation}
 g_n(x,y)=z_n\prod_{k\ne n}\frac{(x-x_k)}{(x_n-x_k)}
 \end{equation}
    Then for $m\ne n$
    \begin{equation}
 g_n(x_n,y_n)=z_n
 \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
 g_n(x_m,y_m)=0
 \end{equation}
    Then define
    \begin{equation}
 f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{7}g_n(x,y)
 \end{equation}

Then for $1\le n\le7$,  $f(x_n,y_n)=z_n$.

Comment: Had to reach back to a graduate class in numerical analysis I took over 50 years ago for this one.

Comment: Just asking, what do you mean by Socratic method? Philosophical method?

Comment: @NSJ Was your question about Socratic method intended for me?

Comment: Yes. I see it in your profile.

Comment: @NSJ I do not see anything about the Socratic method in my profile. However, I did take courses by Drs. R. L. Moore and H. S. Wall at the University of Texas in the 1960s and by students of theirs in the early 1970s who used a type of Socratic teaching method to train research mathematicians. For example, Dr. Moore would give examples of a concept and ask the students to give a definition. We would be asked to prove a proposition or find a counterexample. That sort of approach.